# JRE 7 update 25 checking the JNLP multiple times

Tags: java, jar, manifest, java-web-start, jnlp

I have been recently updated to JRE 7 update 25. And now whenever I download the JNLP (from my develop server), it always shows in the Java Console a warning like this

```
     Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: xxx.jar
     Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: xxx.jar
     Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: xxx.jar
     Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: xxx.jar
```

It is clear that because I didn't put the Codebase attribute to the Manifest file. The strange thing is the warning appears 4 times for each jar file. So I guessed that the new JRE read the jar files multiple times. It is maybe the cause for the slow performance when loading the JNLP (compare to the old JRE - JRE 7 update 10)

Please anyone faced this problem help me!
Thank you!

Comment: ..Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, the question is why the checking of Missing Codebase happen multiple times for each jar file when I load the JNLP ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just file it to JBS JIRA (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net)?